# Extracting rows from .mat table using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

What I have is a variable `X` which has values assigned to it in the form of a table of 9 columns and around 100 rows. Here is an example:

```
X =

  Columns 1 through 7

   -2.2869   -1.1168    0.1430   -4.0753    1.7620   -6.3229   -3.1997
   -2.2504   -1.1022    0.2046   -3.9865    1.7423   -6.2172   -3.1231
   -2.2138   -1.0876    0.2663   -3.8977    1.7226   -6.1115   -3.0465
   -2.1772   -1.0730    0.3279   -3.8089    1.7029   -6.0058   -2.9700
```

I need to create a for loop that extracts the first `r` rows of the first 'p' colmuns. For example `r=3` and `p=4`.

Any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use a for-loop, but rather index directly into the matrix:

```
out = X(1:r,1:p)
```

returns the first `r` rows and `p` columns of `X`.

Comment: This solution gives me exactly what I want the program to do, but part of the assignment is using a for loop in the first place, and I need to produce a function file at the end, which takes p and r as inputs. I will try to iterate on that a bit, but thanks thought!

Comment: Actually this is the correct method, but I will later on use the for loop to plot a graph...